# import discord ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord'

Tags: python, bots, discord

I know there are lots of these posts and I've looked at them but none match mine. I've been running this same code for around a month now and today it just stopped. This is the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import discord
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord'
```

I copy-pasted this whole code (all 700 lines) to a different file, and that worked for about an hour before doing the exact same thing. I want to fix this cause I need this bot running. I have installed python already, and I tried reinstalling it but it said all the requirements were satisfied. I need help. Why is this happening?

Update: I left it sitting for a few hours and it works again. I'm using Repl.it. Is it an issue on their end?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the exact python-engine? (Is there more than one python engines installed on your machine?)

Comment: Not that I'm away of. I've made tons of bots and only 1 other had this problem

Comment: How did you run the script? Can you try using the full path of the `python.exe`?

Comment: There's no point now. It's working fine. I think it may have been an issue on Repl's side.

Comment: I see , glad it worked out. BTW - If this question isn't relevant anymore it will be great of you close it.

Comment: ok, now I just have to figure out how to do that.